# Can't update iOS NSManagedObject property

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm working on a note-app and I'm having some trouble with core data. The problem I'm having is that on of my NSManagedObject object properties (NSString) doesn't get updated after the app has been terminated. Scenario: (1) Build & Run the app, (2) write something (UITextView), (3) press home button (background), (5) Terminate the app, (6) Open the app and the text is there, (7) edit the text (or remove the text), (8) Press home button, (9) Terminate the app, (10) open the app again and the new text isn't there.

I think I have localized the error to this code snippet/method:

```
// Helper method to change page, it takes one argument, tag of the next/prevoius page.
// This method is called in viewWillAppear.
- (void)goToPage:(int)tag
{
    // Set up the new current page. 
    currentPage = [pageList objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSLog(@"%@", currentPage.pageText); // Returns the old value, not the updated. 
    if ([currentPage.inputType isEqualToString:@"drawing"]) {
        [pageView changeToDrawing];
        toolSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

        UIImage * pageImage = [UIImage imageWithData:currentPage.pageImage];
        pageView.canvas.image = pageImage;
    } else if ([currentPage.inputType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        [pageView changeToText];
        toolSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

        pageView.pageText.text = currentPage.pageText;
        if (editing) {
            [undoButton removeFromSuperview];
            [redoButton removeFromSuperview];
        }
    } 
    [self updateMenu];
}
```

When I run `NSLog(@"%@", currentPage.pageText);` it shows that the value haven't been updated/saved.

I set the value like this:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    currentPage.pageText = textView.text;
}
```

I Initially set the current page like this:

```
// Sets the current page to the last open page
currentPageTag =  pagesNoteblock.lastOpenPage;
currentPage = [pageList objectAtIndex:currentPageTag];
```

And create new pages like this:

```
NSString * currentInputType;
if (currentPage.inputType == @"drawing") {
    currentInputType = @"drawing";
} else if ([currentPage.inputType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    currentInputType = @"text";
}

// Sets the current page.
Page * newPage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
newPage.createdAt = [NSDate date];
newPage.inputType = currentInputType;

// Adds the new page to the database and to the pageList array.
[pagesNoteblock addNoteblockPagesObject:newPage];
[pageList addObject:newPage];

// Sets the current page and clears the textView.
currentPage = [pageList objectAtIndex:currentPageTag];
```

I also have a helper method that should save the page content, this is called in viewWillDisapears and some other places:

```
// Method that saves the current page's image to the database.
- (void)savePageContent
{
    // Saves the image to the database.
    if ([currentPage.inputType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        currentPage.pageText = pageView.pageText.text;
    } else if ([currentPage.inputType isEqualToString:@"drawing"]) {
        NSData * coreDataImage = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(pageView.canvas.image)];
        currentPage.pageImage = coreDataImage;
    }
    pagesNoteblock.lastOpenPage = currentPageTag;
}
```

Any help/tips would be appreciated!

Update: Small clarification, it seems like the "Page-text" object is only writable once, i.e. I can only make "savable" changes to it when I first create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas, but not quite sure:

1. Are you sure, when you hit the home button the `textViewDidEndEditing` is being called?
2. I suspect the following method is doing what you want to.

   Page * newPage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

This method inserts (or creates) a new instance / record for Page Class. It dose not update any record that already exist! I don't see you fetch request, but when you fetch from your database, you get an array, and I assume you are displaying only the first one (atIndex:0).

In other words, you are saving it, but as a new record at the end of your database list. You are not updating the one that is already being displayed.

Comment: 1. Yes and no. It gets saved when I hit the done button, thinking of moving it to `textViewDidChange`but it should still work. 2. Thats a really good point, but I tried with an NSlog in my create page method where the code you inserted exists, and it is only getting called when I want it to.

Comment: Lost some hair over this one. Was a silly mistake as usual. In my custom NSManagedObject I had  implemented the text property as `@syntezise` when it should be `@dynamic`. Thanks anyway @Canopus and @gamBit

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm it doesnt look like you are ever calling save on your NSManagedObjectContext, do your objects still come up after you terminate the app? They are saving?

Something similar to this should work after your insert and delete:

```
NSError *error;
[self.context save:&error];
```

`self.context` being whatever your NSManagedObjectContext is.

Comment: Hi, I do the saving in my app delegate/controller, in appWillResignActive and appWillTerminate (or what they are called (not home right now)).Do I need to save in my other view controller too? This problem only occurs with the text view, the app also supports "drawing", which is saved/updated as it should. So I suspect that the problem is related to something else than saving.